# CSV File Upload in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

How can i upload csv file to java class in flex ?

Comment: upload to java class? what are you using at the server side?

Comment: server side technology is java

Comment: It's considered as polite to document the research effort you made before asking a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//the following code will post your csv string to the url specified by serverUrl
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(serverUrl);
req.data = csvString;
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
loader.load(req);
```

Comment: Thanks for that,,

but how can i upload one file from client into my application.??

Comment: Use FileReference class. Call the browse method to let the user select the file, listen to its select event, and call upload from the select-handler. You cannot upload without user consent. FileReference is the only way to upload files from user machine to server using flash. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html